# Where is #Temp Stored ? OR How is #temp Stored

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp

I know #temp is temp. Table valid for particular session only. but if i define #temp in two different session, and run them simultaneously will that conflict. if no then how actually these tables are stored in memory. And how is that different from ##Temp?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CREATE TABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

> The full name of a temporary table as stored in the sysobjects table
>   in **tempdb** is made up of the table name specified in the CREATE TABLE
>   statement and the system-generated numeric suffix.

So it is stored in the tempdb.

Also from [Temporary Tables in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/)

> Temporary tables and table variables are created in the TempDB
>   database

Comment: Okay this means that,even though i am calling these table with same names, system is identifying them by different names ??

Answer (score 2):

Temporary tables with a single # are "local", while those with a double ## are "global".

Local ones will drop out of scope once the stored procedure that defines them is done.

Global ones can be used by other users, or by the same user from different stored procedures, or by multiple calls of the same procedure. They will get dropped only after the last user that was referencing them is no longer referencing them, i.e. after the last stored proc is complete.

All are stored in the tempdb database; none in the "memory".